# Which is most prefered and lightweight way to show your Last Tweet using php?

Tags: php, twitter

I need to Display Last Tweet on a web-page and want to control the styling of tweet from CSS. What is the good way to do this and Tweet should also be seen even if **Javascript is disabled**.

Page is on PHP server.

**Edit**

I just want to show last tweet on a page like this.

```
<div id="last-tweet">
<p>Content of tweet here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Twitter REST API.

```
$api_url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=USERNAME';
$twitter_data = file_get_contents($api_url);
$twitter_data = json_decode($twitter_data);
echo '<div id="last-tweet"><p>' . $twitter_data[0]->text . '</p></div>';
```

Replace `USERNAME` with your username.

http://dev.twitter.com/doc#rest-api

http://php.net/file-get-contents

http://php.net/json-decode

Comment: @Jonah - Thnaks for the answer. How to use this in a html page? Would you pls give more detail

Comment: @Jitendra: It's a PHP script.  Do you know how to write PHP?  Right now it's only in a raw data format; you'll need to write some more code to turn it into the HTML format you want.

Comment: @Jitendra: oops, I was using some outdated code.  See my edit.

Comment: @Jitendra: As it is now, it won't show any tweets.  If you edit your question to specify exactly how you want the HTML formatted, I can add that part for you.

Comment: @Jonah - Thanks Very much. your given code is working fine. Great help.

Comment: This is great and far more efficient than retrieivng the tweet through an RSS feed. I needed to link to @ and links automatically, so I've answered with the code for that (can't include in comment).

Answer (score 1):

Building on Jonah's answer, here's how to do the exact same but automatically link to other mentioned users and links:

```
$api_url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=YOURUSERNAME';
$twitter_data = file_get_contents($api_url);
$twitter_data = json_decode($twitter_data);
$tweet = '<div id="last-tweet"><p>' . $twitter_data[0]->text . '</p></div>';

// Turn URLs into links
$tweet = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $tweet);

// Turn @replies into links
$tweet = preg_replace("/@([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>", $tweet);

echo $tweet;
```